# How to iterate lines of a layer in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have wiring project in macromedia flash mx 2004. I want co calculate total length of wires, thats why I have to iterate lines collection of the wires layer.  I guess the code may look like this:

```
var totalLength = 0;
for each (var line in document.layers('wires').lines()){
    totalLength+=line.length();
}
```

Comment: nope you can't do that.

Comment: I can't believe this, sorry.

Comment: can you confirm if your 'lines' are created using the Graphics class (lineTo etc) or if they're objects on the stage - such as movieclips? If the Graphics api then no, not unless you've stored the coordinates for the created vertexes that you could then look over.

Comment: I drawed them manually.  Tell me how to iterate objects on the stage and I will check.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.

1. Export to *.ai
2. Convert ai to svg
3. Calculate total length (put svg tag into html):

   $(function()
   {
       var l = 0;
       $('path').each(function()
       {
           l+=this.getTotalLength();
       });
       alert(l);
   });

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're drawing in the authoring tool and as far as I know, there is no way to retrieve the coordinates with actionscript 2. You could with something like [as3swf](https://github.com/claus/as3swf), but you're using flash mx 2004.

You can use JavaScript however to script the Flash IDE. Here is a link to the the [CS5 JSFL reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/flash_cs5_extending.pdf)(pdf link). For your needs, most of it is still relevant, alternatively you could get a cheap 2nd hand copy of [Extending Flash MX 2004](http://www.apress.com/9781590593042) which is great if you want to learn how make tools and plugins.

Here's a brief naive example using JSFL to traverse a selected shape and add together the lengths between each vertex (assuming you're only using straight lines):

```
var doc = fl.getDocumentDOM();
if(doc.selection.length > 0){
    var s = doc.selection[0];
    if(s.toString().indexOf("Shape") > 0){//there is probably a nicer way of checking the selection type
        var numVerts = s.vertices.length;//get the total number of vertices
        var totalLength = 0;//store total length
        for(var i = 1; i < numVerts; i++)//loop through each vertex except the 1st
            totalLength += dist(s.vertices[i],s.vertices[i-1]);//accumulate the length of the current and previous vertices to the total
        alert("totalLength:"+totalLength);//display the result
    }
}
function dist(v0,v1){
    var dx = v1.x - v0.x;
    var dy = v1.y - v0.y;
    return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}
```

To use this straight away go to **File > New > Flash JavaScript File**,
then paste the code and run it (using the Run Script(arrow) button).
Be sure to select a Shape in your flash document first.

Have a look at the documentation, especially for the Shape object as you'll get more details on dealing with curves and more complex paths. Also, if you save the script in the right directory (I can't remember where this was for flash mx 2004), you should be able to run it from the Commands menu in Flash and also assign a keyboard shortcut.